# Get counts of each sub-group within main

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I would like to get the counts of each sub-group that appear in the main group.

Given the following:

```
| Clothing    | Colour
-----------------------
| Shirt       | black   
| Shirt       | black  
| Shirt       | black
| Shirt       | yellow 
| Shoes       | yellow
| Shoes       | yellow
| Shoes       | black
```

My desired output would be:

```
| A                    | B
---------------------------
| Shirt_Blacks         | 3 
| Shirt_Yellows        | 1
| Shoes_Blacks         | 1
| Shoes_Yellows        | 2
```

EDIT: Output format 2:

```
| Clothing       | Black | Yellow
-----------------------------------
| Shirt          | 3     | 1
| Shoes          | 1     | 2
```

Tried the following with no luck:

```
SELECT COUNT(Colour) 
FROM [randomtable]
Group By Clothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Clothing, '_', Colour) A, COUNT(*) B
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Clothing, Colour
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a23edcd39d29d2560f39b5dc3adcb0fe)**:

```
A            |  B
:----------- | -:
Shirt_black  |  3
Shoes_black  |  1
Shirt_yellow |  1
Shoes_yellow |  2
```

---

If you are looking to pivot the resultset, then:

```
SELECT 
    Clothing,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Colour = 'Black' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Black,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Colour = 'Yellow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Yellow
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Clothing
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question please. I made an edit to my post in terms of output format. How must I adjust the query to generate output format 2? Thanks again mate! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can group by concat(clothing, '_', colour):

```
SELECT
  concat(clothing, '_', colour) A, 
  COUNT(*) B
FROM [randomtable]
Group By concat(clothing, '_', colour)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Clothing+'_'+Colour A, COUNT(*) B
    FROM [randomtable]
GROUP BY Clothing+'_'+Colour

select * from [randomtable]
    pivot
(count(colour) for colour in (black,yellow))AS piv
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by explaining how it addresses the question. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer